# Docker bridge change docker0 and internal ip

Tags: ip, docker

I  used to  docker  and this docker occured me upon solrcloud.Each for solr create docker0 bridge on IP .For  instance ; this ip : 172.17.47.5.
But , I  want this  ips like 192.168.2.x. Can  I help you?

Comment: To make your container discoverable, simply run the container with specified port. For e.g. 'docker run -d --port 3000:3000 webapp' your container is now discoverable by pointing to hostIp:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy to understand your question, but if I'm right, you just need to use the --ip parameter when you call your docker run, as explained here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

Comment: I  try  "sudo docker run --ip=0.0.0.0 ubuntu:14.04"  I think haven't got " --ip " tag.I saw terminal also those ;  Usage: docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container

  -a, --attach=[]            Attach to stdin, stdout or stderr.
  -c, --cpu-shares=0         CPU shares (relative weight)
  --cidfile=""               Write the container ID to the file
  --cpuset=""                CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3,

Answer (score -1):

I  try command line "sudo  docker run  --ip=192.168.2.35 ubuntu:14.04 " . I  think haven't got " --ip " tag.I saw  terminal also those ;

```
Usage: docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container

  -a, --attach=[]            Attach to stdin, stdout or stderr.
  -c, --cpu-shares=0         CPU shares (relative weight)
  --cidfile=""               Write the container ID to the file
  --cpuset=""                CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
  -d, --detach=false         Detached mode: Run container in the background, print new container id
  --dns=[]                   Set custom dns servers
  --dns-search=[]            Set custom dns search domains
  -e, --env=[]               Set environment variables
  --entrypoint=""            Overwrite the default entrypoint of the image
  --env-file=[]              Read in a line delimited file of ENV variables
  --expose=[]                Expose a port from the container without publishing it to your host
  -h, --hostname=""          Container host name
  -i, --interactive=false    Keep stdin open even if not attached
  --link=[]                  Add link to another container (name:alias)
  --lxc-conf=[]              (lxc exec-driver only) Add custom lxc options --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = 0,1"
  -m, --memory=""            Memory limit (format: <number><optional unit>, where unit = b, k, m or g)
  --name=""                  Assign a name to the container
  --net="bridge"             Set the Network mode for the container
                               'bridge': creates a new network stack for the container on the docker bridge
                               'none': no networking for this container
                               'container:<name|id>': reuses another container network stack
                               'host': use the host network stack inside the contaner.  Note: the host mode gives the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.
  -P, --publish-all=false    Publish all exposed ports to the host interfaces
  -p, --publish=[]           Publish a container's port to the host
                               format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort
                               (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)
  --privileged=false         Give extended privileges to this container
  --rm=false                 Automatically remove the container when it exits (incompatible with -d)
  --sig-proxy=true           Proxify all received signal to the process (even in non-tty mode)
  -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-tty
  -u, --user=""              Username or UID
  -v, --volume=[]            Bind mount a volume (e.g. from the host: -v /host:/container, from docker: -v /container)
  --volumes-from=[]          Mount volumes from the specified container(s)
  -w, --workdir=""           Working directory inside the container
```